# Trying to delete mySQL record from HTML form... NOT WORKING

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html form with a select drop down list populated from mySQL, which correctly retrieves and displays the data in select drop down list.

BUT, I can't get the **delete.php** to work correctly.  Here is the script for the select.php and delete.php.

```
<select name="name">
<?php
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $line['part_no'];?>"> <?php echo $line['part_no'];?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

delete.php

```
<?
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query = "delete from cartons_current where name = '".$name."'";
if(mysql_query($query)){
echo "deleted";}
else{
echo "fail";}
?>
```

Comment: Nice SQL injection hole you've got there... shame if something were to happen to your database... Also, nice query call... shame if you were to neglect for error conditions by checking `mysql_error()` after you try the query.

Comment: `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` plz, inb4 [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: its almost as if everyone on the stack network has the urls to bobby tables and the password length xkcd on a sticky note.

Comment: Are you sure that the $line['part_no'] actually contains a name from the cartons_current table?

Comment: In what way is this not working correctly? Is the record not being deleted from the database, does the script echo `fail` instead of `deleted`? Both?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the comments trailing above, it looks like the heckler's will just heckle. Some of us are still learning to program on stack, so I'm going to try to help.

Are you having column select issues - your while loop is not outputting values from the column you want the delete field match to go with?

Your sql query suggests you are polling a match against the name column, but your select dropdown seems about part_no.

Try: `DELETE from cartons_current WHERE part_no=`...

--

Also, as a first level prevention against SQL injection attacks, try sanitizing all your $_REQUEST field parameters (say, they're called `$var`) with

`$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var)`